# Flexbox ширина column внутри row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Имеется таблица с прокруткой на flexbox. В первом столбце текст, выходящий за пределы ячейки, скрывается `overflow: hidden`.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqqm73v7/)

При попытке обернуть таблицу в дополнительный контейнер `flex-direction: row`, с целью добавить столбец по высоте таблицы, ширина таблицы нарушается.

[Пример 2](https://jsfiddle.net/r62uh6je/)

В чем ошибка и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробывать установить ширину таблицы 100% не пробывал?

```
    .table {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1;
        background: gainsboro;
    }
```

Вот таким методом выходит, что таблица показывается, как в первом примере!

Comment: Выходит что таблица занимает 100% ширины. А новый столбец с `min-width: 40px` уходит за пределы. Размер столбца должен быть фиксированным. Использовать `calc()` я не могу.